# Change Pimple with Symfony dependency injection

Tags: symfony, dependency-injection, silex

Is there a way to swap Pimple with Symfony dependency injection?

I can use Symfony dependency injection as a standalone package with Silex but i need to swap Pimple with it because i can't access controllers registered with Symfony dependency injection from Silex like:

```
$app->get('/route', 'testController:indexAction');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you can't. Silex does not allow to change the container as the Silex main class extends from Pimple itself. If you need the Symfony container you should go with Symfony and not with Silex.

You could hack up a solution in which every call to Pimple is forwarded to DIC (Pimple would be a kind of proxy service only), but I wouldn't go that route.

Keep in mind that with the upcoming Symfony 4 (due on November, but there is a [preview already aviable](http://fabien.potencier.org/symfony4-demo.html)) the framework is going to be more like Silex: instead of having it all and remove the parts you don't use, you'll start small and add components/bundles/libraries into your project (check out [Symfony flex](https://github.com/symfony/flex)).

Finally, as a side note/fun fact, there was a project from igorw (one of the coauthors of Silex) which replaced Pimple with Symfony DIC component, but it was more an academic exercise rather than a ready to use framework (it did work)